# Using php match the two variables contents

Tags: php, mysql

I have some content like below.if i changed the below content how can i found out in php,mysql ? Im using tinymce editor.

In some of the cases it is not working why ? if im using spaces or some regular expresssion why so  ?

```
  $var = "<p>- sdfsdfname as stated in P/O</p><p>- fsdfssupermarfsfked order number</p><p>- DSI: sdf</p><p>- sdfsf&amp; Co dsfnumber</p><p>- sfdsnumber</p><p>- Barcode no. and barcode(scanable)</p><p>- fQuantity of sales units containing each handling unit</p><p>- sdfof sales dsfs, colour/size</p><p>- sfsweight</p><p>- Net weight</p><p>- fdsdfsfunit marked 1 and up</p><p>- fsffor: (sdfsfname)</p>";

  $var1 = "<p>- sdfsdfname as stated in P/O</p><p>- fsdfssupermarfsfked order number</p><p>- DSI: sdf</p><p>- sdfsd&amp; Co dsfnumber</p><p>- sfdsnumber</p><p>- Barcode no. and barcode(scanable)</p><p>- fQuantity of sales units containing each handling unit</p><p>- sdfof sales dsfs, colour/size</p><p>- sfsweight</p><p>- Nesdfsdfst weight</p><p>- fdsdfsfunit marked 1 and up</p><p>- fsffor: (sdfsfname)</p>";
```

**PHP**

```
if($var == $var1){
echo "if";
}else{
echo "else";
}
```

Comment: The code you provided should work - so what exactly is your question?

Comment: use === in your if statement and it'll be fine if clause is they're unchanged else clause would be changed.

Comment: in some of the cases it is not working why ? if im using spaces or some regular expresssion why so  ?

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](http://codepad.org/qjM0ZnN0) this behaviour. Are you sure there is nothing between setting the variables and the `if` which might interfer?

Comment: i cant understand ur question @kingkero

Comment: Click the link and you'll see that for both comparisons it returns `false` (as it should). So the comparison should work. However, could it be that you have something like `$var = $var1;` somewhere?

Comment: no @kingkero somewhere may be the spaces included once its stop working i dont know where im going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I can assure you that if `$var1` is the least bit different to `$var` then you will get the else section of your code. The fact that sometimes you are not points to two possible problems.

1. `$var1` does not receive the changes. This seems unlikely to be honest but it is one of the two things that could go "wrong" and have PHP see the two variables as the same.
2. `$var` is also updated with the new string. This is more likely as this smells to me like a work-flow problem. The question I would be asking would be: Where is the script getting $var from? Presumably you set it before the changes are examined but after the data is returned by the user?

In debugging issues like this it helps to have the script spit out everything it has between two `<pre>` tags. Then you can examine all your variables and find out which ones are not as you were expecting.

```
<?php
  echo "<pre>\n";
  echo "\$var = \"{$var}\"\n";
  echo "\$var1 = \"{$var1}\"\n";
  print_r($some_array);
  // etc
```

Your if-then-else is correct so the question is what is happening with the variables.